# Tor is blocked for me now (I'm in turkey) what can I do?

Tags: censorship

I tried to use the Tor Browser but it doesn't seem to work, I'm in turkey

Comment: Yes, Tor started to work but browsing became slow. I dont know if it is due to this change.

Comment: You can try setting up a personal VPN server with [Streisand](https://github.com/jlund/streisand). It will set up a Tor bridge for you, as well as a suite of VPNs.

Answer (score 8):

There seem to be some censorship events happening in Turkey. If you're having problems connecting to Tor, use obfs4 or meek-amazon. 
(*Türkiye de bazı sansür olayları yaşanıyor gibi görünüyor. Tor'a bağlanırken sorun yaşarsanız köprülerden meek-amazon'u kullanın.*)

[image]

Comment: This does not work. I tried all the bridges one-by-one. Cannot establish a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try VPNgate 
http://www.vpngate.net/en/
You may use VPNgate alone, or once you get connected to one of the VPNgate server, you can turn on Tor for extra anonymity.

Comment: Some random VPN may be sufficient to stop it looking like Tor to a naive observer but it's fragile. Furter analysis of traffic patterns in the VPN connection may reveal the VPN traffics nature and the VPN itself would be trivial to block (more trivial than tor + pluggable transports).

Comment: You may search the paper about VPNgate to see how it is better than Tor against blocking effort of China.